# Rails get session by sessiond_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, sessionid

In my Rails app,my `session` is stored in memory

Now I want to get all sessions of specified user by his `session_id`,what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

> `request.session_options[:id]`

Comment: not session_id,I want to get `session` by `session_id`